# while loop ending after calling a function

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to create a prime factorization function (recursively), my issue is that the while loop ends after calling the function itself.

Code:

```
primeFactors(){
    if isPrime $1; then
        echo "$1"
    else
        i=2
        sqrtnum=`echo "sqrt($1)"|bc`
        while [ $i -lt $sqrtnum ]
        do
            echo "I: $i sqr: $sqrtnum"
            j=$(($1%i))
            if isPrime $i && [ $j -eq 0 ]
            then
                echo "$i"
                num=$(($1/$i))
                primeFactors $num
            fi
            let i++
        done
    fi
}
```

The output is this

```
I: 2 sqr: 10
2
I: 2 sqr: 7
2
I: 2 sqr: 5
I: 3 sqr 5
I: 4 sqr 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables are global.

Later function calls override earlier assignments.

You need to make the variables `local`.

Add `set -x` to the top of your script to see what is actually being run.